# Why did my reputation decrease 20 points with a 'User was removed' summary?

Tags: bug, reputation

You can see in the next picture that my reputation has decreased 20 points, and the summary says *"User was removed"*.

[image: screenshoot]

I cannot understand nothing of what happened here.

Can someone explain to me what just happened?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A user that gave you up votes was removed for something "not good" and thus their history was removed as well. Maybe a bot up-voted something to look more legit.

See [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation)

Comment: Really? Is there any page in the documentation where I can see that? If that is true, I think that the method to let me know about it could be improved. At lest, the summary (user was removed) is confusing..

Comment: That could be reworded to: User that upvoted your post was deleted.

Comment: added link to answer

Comment: Don't assume deleted accounts are because of something "not good." That's typically *NOT* the case. It's ***much*** more common for users to request an account removed for *other* reasons, like anonymity or basic management of their online presence.

Comment: I thought those were just "disabled" and not "removed". That their points stayed.